# iRedMail missing apache2-mod-auth-mysql

Tags: mysql, apache, email, installation, ubuntu-12.04

Whenever I try and install iRedMail, it gives me and error saying that apache2-mod-auth-mysql is a missing dependency and I tried installing it but there is no such package

I keep getting this error The following packages have unmet dependencies: libapache2-mod-auth-mysql : Depends: apache2.2-common (>= 2.2.3-3) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. I've even tried updating apache, reinstalling it, but all in vain...

Answer (score 0):

You can install it by running

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-mysql
```

Comment: I got this error `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-auth-mysql : Depends: apache2.2-common (>= 2.2.3-3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.` I've even tried updating apache, reinstalling it, but all in vain...

Comment: What is your apache version?